# Rails association HABTM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, ruby-on-rails-5, model-associations

I need some help in creating association for my new rails application.

I have two models `User` and `Profession`. A user might have many professions and profession might belongs to many users.

I can do `HABTM` association in both the models.

User `has_and_belongs_to_many :professions`

Profession `has_and_belongs_to_many :users`

I want professions table should hold only unique profession name and assign them to many users. But if I try to create professions for users like bellow

```
user1.professions.create(name: "Dev")

user2.professions.create(name: "Dev")
```

Both profession "Dev" will get saved in professions table.

How to save unique profession name in Profession model and can assign them to many users?

Comment: How about something like `user1.professions << Profession.find_or_create_by(name: 'Dev')`?

Comment: @MarekLipka Thanks. That does the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest splitting it into two steps.

At first find or create profession:

```
profession = Profession.find_or_create_by(name: "Dev")
```

Then assign the profession to user:

```
user1.professions << profession
user2.professions << profession
```

I would also recommend to set a unique index on `professions` table's `name` column. It will guarantee the uniqueness.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create association as below:

```
profession = Profession.find_or_create_by(name: "Dev")
user1.professions << profession

profession = Profession.find_or_create_by(name: "Dev")
user2.professions << profession
```